# A numeric definition which determines volatile and non-volatile compounds?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

*Important conditions*: stripping by air from water.
Hypothetical example: Let’s say **if Henry’s constant is e.g. 0.005**, everything *below is non-volatile*, *everything above volatile.*
The problem is I cannot find any study which determines which any constant that can tell me this compound is considered volatile, or not.

I am trying to determine which compounds during aeration of industrial wastewater will strip fast/as first.
I have tables of Henry's constant but I cannot determine which is the border of "normally volatile compounds".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_organic_compound While this is only discussing organics, it does show what constitutes "volatile" depends on what regulatory body you are following.